# TextBoxFor() not generating validation markup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a SQL Server 2012 in which I have AWARD table with two columns TITLE and MONTH. TITLE is varchar(256) and cannot be NULL. MONTH is int and can be NULL.

With VS2012 Ultimate and EF 5.0.0, the TextBoxFor helper in MVC4 app is not producing validation  `(data-val="required" and data-val-required="required message")` for the TITLE columne above, but in the same View, MONTH is getting the correct validation markup. The .edmx designer does show TITLE is NonNullable, BUTT, the automatically generated AWARD.cs file does not have the `[Required]` 
attribute for the TITLE column.

What can I try?

```
@model MyProject.Models.AWARD

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Award";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EditorLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Award</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TITLE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TITLE)
                    <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TITLE)
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MONTH)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MONTH, new SelectList(MyProject.Models.Helpers.Months, "key","value"), "[Not Selected]")
                <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MONTH)
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "cancel-button" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Can you post your viewmodel?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't really be binding your views directly to your data mapping entities. You should create **view model** classes to wrap the data you pass to and from your view and then populate your data objects from the controller.

You can then perform the required validation on your view model without affecting your generated mapping classes.

**Model**

```
public class AwardViewModel
{
    [Required, StringLength(30)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**View**

```
@model AwardViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
    ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create (AwardViewModel model)
{
    /* Create new AWARD in entity context, populate
       with relevant fields from model and commit. */
}
```

Comment: Ant P that's the same "answer" I have found across various forums, and from my little experience that approach comes with its own baggage - like missing navigation (relational database) properties- unless you match the DatabaseModel ditto inyour ViewModel. I even agree with you - but I would like to solve the problem at hand: WHY is TextBoxFor not giving validation HTML but DropDownListFor is - within the same HTML form.

Comment: Also - I know I can add the validation markup myself in the TextBoxFor and be done with it, or add `[Required]` attribute inthe AWARD.cs file under my .edmx tree. But that to me is more like a hack.

Comment: pasting here for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000812/varchar-columns-nullable-or-not

Comment: Much much helpful link - until MS comes up with some kind of alternate view on generating code from database: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ace90833-e783-423d-9545-ce8b3b8cca08

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by missing navigation properties - this is the whole point of a view model. Your view model is a **model** for your **view**, not for your data entities. You give it whatever information the **view** needs and this is not necessarily restricted to information from one business entity/class. There is not really any question that sharing your business entities directly with your view is poor practice - it will lead you directly into issues like the one you have here. Your views do not need to (and, indeed, shouldn't) know about your data model.

Comment: Ant P you're right - I agree. Bad coding on my part. But my question is really based on the assumption that EF does not care whether I share business entity with view or not. That's my choice. EF needs to do its job to provide proper Nullable and/or data annotations.